# Is it possible to do shipping like this in Magento?

Tags: ecommerce, magento

What I need is to have Magento charge a flat rate shipping for orders under a certain amount, and free shipping for orders over that amount. It's like having two flat rates. I have tried setting a flat rate and free shipping together but it just gives the option to the customer to chose between them via a radio button; which is not what I need.

Comment: Suffering the same problem, I've been in this situation for months and it's still amazing how many people will pick 'standard shipping' and pay rather than 'free next-day delivery'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea was good add free and flat rate and then you will just need a little hack in your template:

go to template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml and brake the for each as folow

```
</dd>
    <?php //EGS to avoid other methods show up if freeshipping is in place ?>
    <?php if($code=="freeshipping"){ break; } ?>
```

In the admin be sure you put the freeshipping first.

Comment: Thanks... I'll accept your answer because you seem to know, and I'm sure it would work if I tried it. As it so happens my client has done a direction change with this so I don't need it now; and I don't have time to try it out wither  ... still I might need it in the future and it's good it's on Stack Exchange now too in case others are in the same boat.